# How can I keep my SSH connection alive while on VPN

Tags: linux, ssh

Since I'm stuck working from home for now I'm running into an annoyance more and more often. My SSH connections to machines at work won't stay alive. This does not happen when I am at work and directly connected to the work network. When I am at home and connected via VPN, if I stop an SSH session for about 10 minutes (e.g. because I'm working on something else), the session dies.

It just becomes unresponsive, but does not actually exit.

Is there something I can do to keep my sessions alive for longer so that I can go make coffee without all of my sessions dying while I'm gone?

Comment: You need keepalives. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084288/keep-ssh-session-alive

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I agree that this is a duplicate and should be closed. I'm unsure if I should just delete the question, though, since my searching didn't bring me to that answer and others may find my question instead.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if this should be flagged as duplicate since the other answer is on SO, not unix.stackexchange and was closed as "off topic" there.